# Debian - How can you install Debian on a USB drive, with grub on an internal drive?

Tags: debian, grub

I have tried it by using guided partitioning on the USB drive, and by creating a single partition with a boot flag and a `msdos` partion table on the internal one. When I tried to boot from the internal drive I only get a black screen. I have copied the `/boot/grub` directory to the internal drive from the USB one, but I still only see a black screen. Ctrl+Alt+Delete doesn't do anything. There is no error message. I am installing Debian 10.9 32-bit on BIOS/Legacy hardware. I have a *feeling* it's installing for UEFI which I do not want and don't know how to prevent. I can eventually try installing ISOLINUX on the USB drive, to circumvent the internal one.

Comment: In your question, I do not fully understand what is a description of the problem (current state) and what you are going for (target state). It is definitively possible to install GRUB for BIOS into the MBR of both, USB and internal drive so both instances of GRUB and Debian are independent from each other. Is that what you want?

Comment: My current state - Debian installed on USB, grub on internal (not working). My target state - Debian installed on USB, either booting directly from the USB or booting with grub from the internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible problems.

Just copying `/boot/grub` to a partition on the internal drive and setting the boot flag on that partition is not enough to make the internal drive bootable.

The active core of the BIOS version of GRUB is normally stored in blocks between the Master Boot Record and the beginning of the first partition in a MBR-partitioned disk. These blocks are not part of any filesystem or partition, and cannot really be copied as files. They also may include a built-in reference that tells the GRUB core where to find the `/boot/grub` directory: this reference is written in when `grub-install` is executed.

Also, the BIOS might support USB Mass Storage devices at boot time *only when you're actually selected to boot from USB*. If your system does not specifically offer USB Mass Storage support at BIOS level when not actually booting from USB, then as far as any program that relies on BIOS (like GRUB) is concerned, the USB Mass Storage device doesn't exist until the actual OS is booted and activates its own USB drivers. And since Debian places its kernel and initramfs files into `/boot/` directory, they will be on the USB and thus inaccessible to GRUB.

You could tell the installer to mount a partition from the internal drive as `/boot`, optionally without formatting it first, so the Linux boot files will just be added to it.

Or just copy the contents of the existing `/boot` directory to a filesystem on the internal drive, mount that filesystem as the new `/boot`, and run `grub-install /dev/sda` (assuming that `/dev/sda` is your internal drive).

In principle, there should be nothing preventing you from installing GRUB on the USB drive. Since you've let the Debian installer partition the USB drive, there should be nothing preventing you from installing GRUB on the USB drive and using it. If you haven't tried just performing a regular installation of Debian onto the USB and then changing the BIOS boot order to boot from USB, try it first before making unnecessary complications.

ISOLINUX is for accessing ISO9660 filesystems through BIOS, and that should not apply to your case at all.

Comment: I have tried installing it fully to the USB drive, but when booting from it I also got a black screen. There might be another issue at hand

Comment: When prompted to install grub I selected the internal drive, which installed it to the MBR, this didn't work so I additionally copied `/boot/grub` to the drive (I didn't copy all of boot, but since drivers need to be loaded for USB support, this might actually be the solution)

Comment: I could try installing it by automatically partitioning the USB drive, then making the internal drive mounted as /boot

Comment: That was the solution, thank you.